# How to Fatch data from shutteratock api using django?

Tags: python, django, shutterstock

view.py:

curl -X GET "https://api.shutterstock.com/v2/images/search" 
--header "Authorization: Bearer $SHUTTERSTOCK_API_TOKEN" 
-G 
--data-urlencode "query=hiking" 
--data-urlencode "image_type=photo" 
--data-urlencode "orientation=vertical" 
--data-urlencode "people_number=3"

Comment: Django is web apps framework, not web scrapper and thus has nothing to do with fetching

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How I can write this code in python Django?